# What is "libgdk" used for in Ubuntu?

Tags: libraries

Please explain me what is libgdk used for in ubuntu. Here is an example where you can find it: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.1200.2

Comment: Does this clarify? [GDK](https://developer-old.gnome.org/platform-overview/stable/tech-gdk.html.en)

Comment: yes, thank you!